# Can I use annotation-based dependency injection including JDBC driver configuration?

Tags: java, jdbc, dependency-injection, annotations

Some days ago I have seen a Java source code example of a class (maybe EJB) which iirc had a JDBC connection field annotated with the complete JDBC configuration (URL, user name, password, driver class). Unfortunately I forgot to keep a bookmark - so my question: is there a DI way to use DI annotations for a complete JDBC configuration, instead of the usual way (using JNDI data sources) in Java?

Comment: I've never seen a standard way to do this, however you can write your own annotations and in HibernateUtils parse the annotations on the class and do whatever you want with the values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a widely used annotation that completely configures a data source, but it would be fairly trivial to write your own. I would also hesitate to call JNDI the "usual way" of configuration data sources. To me, this is the "usual way" of defining a data source in a DI container:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```